# Google Analytics UTM Codes in Conversions Goals

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, utm

I have 2 websites. (Site A and SIte B)

I am passing UTM codes From Site A to Site B page. (Site A page 1 to Site B page 2)
Site A with UTM tracking info - https://www.SiteA.com/?utm_source=MYsource&utm_medium=MY_web&utm_campaign=MY_Testing

Destination - https://www.SiteB.com/registernow.aspx

I can see my UTM tracking info (utm_medium,utm_source,utm_campaign) on RealTime Data (on 'Traffic Sources',Conversions) in real-time. All required information are there.

I can see my UTM tracking info (utm_medium,utm_source,utm_campaign) on Acquisition Data (on 'Campaigns',Conversions). Everything that I need is there too.

But I can not see my UTM tracking info on Conversions --> Goals.
(I have set up the Goal and the Goal name and the UTM data are tracking on 'RealTime Data' and  'Acquisition Data'. But not on Goals. I am trying this for a week now and checking after 24 hours. But the tracking info is not there. I think I can see source/medium as (direct) / (none).)

I just added the UTM to site B to test. (Not through Site A. The Site B itself with adding UTM codes in the URL)
If we open the Goal URL just manually on Site B through an email or through a browser, then it is tracking on 'Conversions --> Goals' with the UTM tracking code.

The problem is when we pass UTM through Site A.

I tried these 2 examples.
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/transfer-utm-parameters-google-tag-manager/
https://www.analyticsmania.com/other-posts/transfer-utms-from-one-page-to-another-with-gtm-version-1/

I am not sure where I have missed it.

I want to get my UTM tracking info to 'Conversions --> Goals' when we pass it through Site A page 1 to Site B page 2.

Please, can you help me to sort this issue out? I really appreciate it if you can support me. It has been more than10 days since to figure out the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/  or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

UTM parameters are automatically deleted from the URL by Google Analytics (Analytics uses them to record their values ​​as source, medium, campaign, ...). You cannot use them as destination Goal, rather enter another parameter to be taken as a reference for the goal on the landing.

UTMs within the same site must not be entered because they generate inconsistent data.

You can see the values ​​you entered in the UTMs in the source / medium report.

**EDIT**:

If you want to use a trick, however, you can create a script that if it detects the UTM in the URL sends an event to Google Analytics so you can set a goal on that event.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Pisani. So there is no way to see the UTM tracking on the Goals? But then how we can see the UTM values when we load the direct URL with UTM within the same site? Is this happening only when we pass it through another website?

Comment: Thank you, Pisani

So can't we pass UTM values from one site to another site and get them on the Conversions -> Goals--> Overview?

Comment: You cannot used them as destination goal.

Comment: Thank you Pisani

In this link, it says that is possible with this script.
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/transfer-utm-parameters-google-tag-manager/

So on which site I need to put this code? Site A or Site B?

I tried both. But not showing on goals.

Comment: The article is not about goals. Anyway I updated my answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and for replying to me.

Anyway, I could do this using Google Tag Manager and the custom script on the link I posted before.

It worked for me and I can see my UTM in the Goal which passed from the external site link.

Thank you!